# Issue in DataBinding in WP7

Tags: image, windows-phone-7, xaml, binding, textblock

This is a really strange issue, this is the last page that i was working on, i used to make an ObservableCollection of the ListBox to add the data in the textblocks and image and bind the data.

But this time i only have 1 TextBlock and 1 Image that i need to bind the Data to it.
In the .cs file, i can't access them directly and also DataBinding is not working.

Xaml:

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding lastName}" Height="33" Margin="0,175,8,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="336" />
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding lastAddress}" Margin="8,291,8,8"/>
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="33" Margin="8,0,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Restaurant Profile: " VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="225" TextDecorations="Underline" Foreground="#FF7A0100" FontSize="24"/>
        <Image Source="{Binding lastImage}" Height="132" Margin="8,37,292,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Stretch="None"/>
    </Grid>
```

Any help ?
Thanks.

Comment: Could you add in the code where you set your `DataContext`. That will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you have a couple of potential problems here. First of all, if you want to access your controls from your codebehind `.cs` file, you need to give the controls names, like this:

```
<Grid Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
    <TextBlock Name="MyTextBlock" />
</Grid>
```

Then they are accessible in your codebehind:

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DoStuff();
}

private void DoStuff() 
{
    MyTextBlock.Text = "Hey, it works!";
}
```

Second, in order to get the databinding working, you need to set the `DataContext` for your page, either in the XAML or in your codebehind file.

In the codebehind file, you can do it like this:

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    LayoutRoot.DataContext = this;
}
```

Which allows you to databind like this:

```
<Grid Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
    <TextBlock Name="MyTextBlock" Text="{Binding MyProperty}"/>
</Grid>
```